# Host Pelican-powered blog on Github pages

Tags: python, github, static-site

I'm trying to host my Pelican-powered blog on Github pages. The source code is here:
https://github.com/garudareiga/devblog

When I use the URL http://garudareiga.github.io/devblog, the site shows without theme. However, if I deploy on heroku (http://raydevblog.herokuapp.com) or open with localhost:8000, the site show with theme.

I could not figure out why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing file

Comment: This is not about a missing file, this is about setting up Pelican properly. The OP should use `SITEURL=https://garudareiga.github.io/devblog` in the `publishconf.py` file (note, I think it should have been `https` by the OP). Pelican will then correctly prepared this to the `href` so that it becomes `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://garudareiga.github.io/devblog/theme/css/main.css">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file does not exist
http://garudareiga.github.io/theme/css/main.css
I think it is necessary to checkin on github

**Edited**
You need to change the file index.html
Of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/main.css">`
To `<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/main.css">`
And all links removes "/" start

Otherwise he will for http://garudareiga.github.io instead of http://garudareiga.github.io/devblog/

http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: It is available as  http://garudareiga.github.io/devblog/theme/css/main.css

Comment: yes put your html rendered as 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/main.css">
With that he ignores the folder devblog

You need to change
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/main.css">

Or create your blog in the root http://garudareiga.github.io

Comment: It works after the change. Thanks.